# How to combine foreground and background Google Nearby Messages BLE-only subscriptions

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-nearby

My goal is to subscribe to Google Nearby Messages in BLE-only mode. While my app is not running (in background or simply not started after phone restart) I want just low-power background scanning. I can live with scanning only on screen-on events.
When the app is active I want to do foreground scanning with fast reactions to found and lost beacons and mainly with distance estimations.

What am I doing now is to subscribe in background (with PendingIntent) in a BroadcastReceiver reacting to "BOOT_COMPLETED" intent. I receive an intent when my app is in background and other application makes a scan. So this part works.

Now when my Activity starts (onResume), I subscribe second time in foreground mode (with MessageListener instead of PendingIntent). And I unsubscribe in onPause. I get updates very fast including distance estimations. So this also works.

The solution has some problems though.

1. When beacon is found the onFound is now called by PendingIntent as well as by MessageListener. So not very good performance-wise solution.
2. When I subscribe in foreground, I first receive onLost for all messages by background receiver. Right after I receive onFound by both background and foreground receivers. The same occurs on unsubscribe call. Leads to ugly flickering and lower performance...
3. The battery consumption is enormous. Mainly after many subscribe/unsubscribe cycles. I was able to completely discharge battery through the night (around 10 hours) when phone was not used at all and thus in background scanning. The battery consumption screen shows Google Play Services as the biggest battery consumer(25%).

Questions:

1. Is there better way how to receive low power results while app is not running and do active foreground scanning while app is running?
2. How are the subscriptions working?  Are they (both background and foreground) persistent between app restarts? Or shall I subscribe on every app start? What happens when I subscribe again without unsubscribing?
3. I see Nearby reaction to Activity becoming inactive in log files. Is the foreground subscription automatically disabled when Activity becomes inactive? Is it automatically enabled when active again? Or is it simply using a lot of battery without any added value?